msal browser not retrieving new token for different clientId as check is only on account
We are using msal browser with session storage. We have mutiple applications on same domain so different applications load based on route. If one of our application is authenticated and we try to navigate to other application by simply updating route in same window, idTokenClaims becomes undefined however accounts are defined. Hence screen is stuck in the loop and never gets the token for new client.
"@azure/msal-browser" : "3.15.0"
@azure/msal-react : "2.0.17"
